# Differences between Private command with no parameters or local token list variable

Tags: best-practices, expl3, latex3

In LaTeX3, what are the differences - both practical and philosophical - between a private command taking no parameters and a local token list variable?  In what situations should one be preferred over the other?  Is there an accepted best practice?

As an example, suppose that I am defining a key to hold font switches such as `\color{red}\itshape`.  Using a private command to store the font switches, I might define:

```
\cs_new:Npn \@@_font: { }

\keys_define:nn { @@ } {
  font .code:n = { \cs_set:Npn \@@_font: {#1} } ,
  font .value_required:n = true ,
  font .initial:n = ,
}
```

On the other hand, using a local token list variable, I might define:

```
\tl_new:N \l_@@_font_tl

\keys_define:nn { @@ } {
  font .tl_set:N = \l_@@_font_tl ,
  font .value_required:n = true ,
  font .initial:n = ,
}
```

Which of these two versions is preferred in LaTeX3?

Comment: The difference is in the concept, rather than in the implementation; both will be a parameterless macro, but the idea is that functions do something, variables store something. In this case, if `font` is used to *define* a font switch, a function is right; if it is *used* in other code, it should probably be a variable.

Comment: Depends imho on the use. A variable should be passed through a function: `\module_use_font:n{\l_@@_font_tl}`, as a standalone call it is a function.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Probably `\module_use_font:V \l_@@_font_tl`

Comment: @TeXnician Done

Answer (score 3):

This is a borderline case. The distinction between functions and variables is that

- functions perform actions
- variable store values

Changing the current font is an action, so in this case I'm more inclined towards a function.

The cleanest way to proceed would be something like

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \@@_use_font:n { #1 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_use_font:n { V }

\keys_define:nn { @@ }
 {
  font .tl_set:N = \l_@@_font_tl  ,
  font .value_required:n = true ,
  font .initial:n = ,
}
```

with

```
\@@_use_font:V \l_@@_font_tl
```

at point of use.

On the other hand, directly using a token list variable is rather common in existing `expl3` code, for efficiency. Thus, for a case like this, it's more personal preference than strict respect of guidelines: the overhead introduced with `\@@_use_font:V` is negligible in this case, in other similar cases efficiency might make the choice of using the variable more attractive.